# Http Digest Authentication, Handle different browser char-sets

Tags: php, utf-8, browser, iso-8859-1, digest-authentication

I tried to use the Http Authentication Digest Scheme with my php (apache module) based website. In general it works fine, but when it comes to verification of the username / hash against my user database i run into a problem.
Of course i do not want to store the user´s password in my database, so i tend to store the A1 hashvalue (which is md5($username . ':' . $realm . ':' . $password)) in my db. 
This is just how the browser does it too to create the hashes to send back.

The Problem:

I am not able to detect if the browser does this in ISO-8859-1 fallback (like firefox, IE) or UTF-8 (Opera) or whatever.  I have chosen to do the calculation in UTF-8 and store this md5 hash. Which leads to non-authentication in Firefox and IE browsers.

How do you solve this problem?

Just do not use this auth-scheme? Or Store a md5 Hash for each charset?

Force users to Opera?

(Terms of A1 refer to the http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php example.)
(for digest access authentication read the according wikipedia entry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for my problem was a bug in FireFox.
Just to answer and close this.
Link:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=546330